# Handle the HTTP PUT method in Python WSGI

Tags: python, http, wsgi, put

I currently have a bash application that, among other things, uses cURL to upload a file to a web application with the PUT method. I am attempting to duplicate the web application as the client (bash) portion is GPL but the web portion is not. I also cannot alter the client application as it auto-updates itself from the developers' website.
I have found multitudes of information on how to handle the HTTP **POST** method with WSGI, CherryPy, Twisted, and practically every way of having Python scripts working on the WWW. However, I can't find a single thing about the **PUT** method. Does anyone know how to process a PUT request with WSGI, or is there some other framework with PUT functionality that I am missing?

Comment: It's really going to depend upon the framework you are using. For django, for instance, you check `request.method`, and see if it is "PUT", "POST", "GET", "DELETE", or whatever else.

Comment: Unfortunately, the application whose server-side I'm duplicating requires usage of various different HTTP status codes, regardless of whether or not they'd actually make sense, which mostly don't -- the bash client just extracts the code out of the response header with `cut` -- Django is thus too low-level for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand it, you will just want to read the stream `environ['wsgi.input']`, because a `PUT` request will send the entire contents of the `PUT` as the body of the request.

I am not aware of any encoding issues you will have to deal with (other than the fact that it is binary).

Some time ago, I wrote a simple set of PHP scripts to take and give huge files from another server on a LAN.  We started with POST, but quickly ran out of memory on the larger files.  So we switched to PUT, where the PHP script could take it's good time looping through `php://input` 4096 bytes at a time (or whatever)...  It works great.

Here is the PHP code:

```
$f1 = fopen('php://input', 'rb');
$f2 = fopen($FilePath, 'wb');

while($data = fread($f1, 4096))
{
    fwrite($f2, $data);
}

fclose($f1);
fclose($f2);
```

From my experience in handling `multipart/form-data` in WSGI with `POST`, I have little doubt that you can handle a `PUT` by just reading the input stream.

The python code should be like this:

```
  output = open('/tmp/input', 'wb')
  while True:
    buf = environ['wsgi.input'].read(4096)
    if len(buf) == 0:
      break
    output.write(buf)
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know PUT was so similar to POST in this regard! I'll try this in a moment.

Comment: Hmm... better make that tomorrow. No offense to you, another task just sprang up that takes priority over this one.